# Why docker (with overlay2 driver storage) change the reported size of a mount point

Tags: docker

I'm having this in my `/etc/sysconfig/docker-storage`

```
DOCKER_STORAGE_OPTIONS="--storage-driver=overlay2"
```

Then I mount `/dev/xdvcz` to `/var/lib/docker/overlay2`.
Then I do a `df -h`:

```
# df -h /dev/xvdcz
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/nvme1n1    938G   72M  888G   1% /var/lib/docker/overlay2
```

That's correct, I have 1000G EBS device.
Now I start docker with `service docker start`.

`df -h` report is now changing to:

```
# df -h /dev/xvdcz
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/nvme1n1    7.8G  7.8G     0 100% /var/lib/docker/overlay2
```

Okay, stop docker: `service docker stop`

`df -h` report is now changing back to:

```
# df -h /dev/xvdcz
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/nvme1n1    938G   72M  888G   1% /var/lib/docker/overlay2
```

Answer (score 1):

`service docker start` is mounting `/var/docker` again, causing the mount I put there initially to become useless.